# Comment selection not working in visual studio community 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, comments

I am trying to comment selected code and I am pressing correct buttons but nothing happens. Maybe someone had this problem, how to fix it?

Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.1

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you add the toolbar to VS?

Comment: @jdweng How to add it?

Comment: From VS menu View : Toolbars : Text Edit.  Not sure if issue is the Toolbar key is not working or the Shortcut you are using.  Your Shortcut key may need to be setup or conflicts with another shortcut key.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, it was conflicting with other shortkeys. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was conflicting with other shortkeys. You should go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Edit.CommentSelection and make other shortcut. I made alt+/. Thanks @jdweng for answer.